# Understanding how lazy functional languages achieve IO (...sometimes?)

Tags: functional-programming

> An Alternative view of I/O programs, popular in earlier **lazy** functional programming languages, was to see the input and output as Strings, that is as lists of characters. Under that model an I/O program is a function
>
> listIOprog :: Str->Str
>
> This obviously makes sense in a 'batch' program, where al, the input is read before any output is produced but in fact it also works for interactive programs where input and output are interleaved, if the language is lazy. **This is because in a lazy language we can began to print the result of a computation - the output of the interactive program here - before the arguement - the interactive input - is fully evaluated.** As an example, repeadtely to rever lines of input under this model one can write
>
> listIOprogram = unlines. map reverse . lines

I don't understand the bolded line. How can we evaluate the output before the actual inputs are given? For eg, take the function Sum x y = x+y, what would it mean to evaluate this without any numbers are given.

Answer (score 1):

Addition is not a good example for this because it does need both of its inputs. Laziness comes into play for functions whose output may not depend on all of the input.

An example of laziness that can be found in virtually all mainstream programming languages is the boolean operator `&&` (and its sibling `||`). Conventionally, `X && Y` first evaluates the expression `X`, then if `X` is true, it evaluates `Y`. But if `X` is false, it skips evaluating `Y`, ignoring any of its side effects.

Lazy evaluation of the following program will interleave input (`read_bool`) and output (`write_bool`):

```
let x = read_bool() in
let y = read_bool() in
write_bool(x && y);
write_bool(y)
```

Lazy evaluation follows demand: we do not evaluate `read_bool()` immediately when we encounter the binding `x = read_bool()`, because `x` might not be needed in the end. Instead, `write_bool` is the operation that drives evaluation, because the value must be known before `write_bool` can print it.

The evaluation of that expression can be broken down as follows, with **IO operations written in bold**.

1. `write_bool(x && y)` demands `x && y`
2. `x && y` demands `x`
3. `x = read_bool()` **reads a boolean**. For example, `x = false`. Now we can go back to the previous expression that demanded `x`.
4. `false && y = false` (by definition of `&&`).
5. `write_bool(false)` **writes `false`**.
6. `write_bool(y)` demands `y`
7. `y = read_bool()` **reads a boolean**. For example, `y = true`.
8. `write_bool(true)` **writes `true`**.

That is how lazy evaluation lets us interleave IO operations even though in the source expression, all input operations appeared before all output operations.